# PowerShell hashtable reference returns null

Tags: powershell, null, hashtable

[image: Null Output]

Based on the above example, why would the result of the above not be 'On'? I'm feeling rather foolish because this is so simple but in any other language `$PowerStateMap[$DeviceStatus.PowerState]` would have returned 'On'. Does PowerShell have some weird trick for referencing a hashtable?

Update: I figured it out... I had to typecast `$DeviceStatus.PowerState` to an int manually. Why did I have to do that?

Edit: For reference:

[image]

Comment: what is `$DeviceStatus.Powerstate.gettype()` ?

Comment: @T-Me Int64 - this is partially why my mind was blown when this didn't work. I had checked the type beforehand and was like yep... Int64 should definitely work.

Comment: The hash table keys are Int32 type. You need to cast to Int32 first -> `$PowerStateMap[[int]$DeviceStatus.PowerState]`

Comment: `Hashtable` is not generic; it uses `object` keys. Unfortunately the .NET equality rules make it so that a boxed `Int64` is not ever considered identical to a boxed `Int32`, no matter their values. This is a leaky abstraction; PowerShell doesn't really "do" anything with boxing, but it suffers the consequences anyway.

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/7571258)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you are dealing with two different numeric types. The hash table contains keys of type `Int32`. The referenced object contains `Int64` values. The simple solution is to just cast the `Int64` values as `Int32` when a hash table value is retrieved.

```
$PowerStateMap[[int]$DeviceStatus.PowerState]
```

---

We can simulate the above with an example:

```
$PowerStateMap = @{
    20 = 'Powering On'
    18 = 'Off'
    17 = 'On'
    21 = 'Powering Off'
}
$DeviceStatus = [pscustomobject]@{PowerState = [int64]17}

$DeviceStatus.PowerState
$DeviceStatus.PowerState.GetType()

"Testing Without Casting"
$PowerStateMap[$DeviceStatus.PowerState]
"Testing with casting"
$PowerStateMap[[int]$DeviceStatus.PowerState]
```

**Output:**

```
17
IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Int64                                    System.ValueType
"Testing Without Casting"
"Testing with casting"
On
```